# How get data from Microsoft Outlook with Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, outlook

I need to get information from Microsoft Outlooks calendar to show it on calendar application which I made with Silverlight.
I can get all needed information with Silverlight 4 but in trusted mode and my application must be installed on users computer and work as Desctop application.
But I need for my application to work on browser.
Is it possible or the only way is using it as Desctop application?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't. The best that you can do is to create a [web service](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/quickstarts/webservices/) to communicate with Silverlight and then an Outlook add-in to communicate with that web service.

Comment: I found in internet that for local networks I can use WebDav server. I can publish my calendar to WebDav server. After that access files located there. Is this right or there is anything which I haven't understand right?

Comment: That's an interesting idea - I haven't seen it done before, but I believe it's possible. I guess the only thing to work out from an SL perspective is how to access/read that calendar file. I'm not sure if Outlook now supports CalDav (the calendar extensions for WebDav), but if it does, even easier.

Answer (score 1):

I did it with WebDav server. I published my calndar to WebDav server. Calendar is on .ics format so I can read all information from it as with other files and then parse it.
My WCF service is on the same computer in which is WebDav so I can get all needed information with Silverlight. I decided to use this version because in this case user have no need to install .Net freamework on his computer. I also found that user can publish his calendar from internet so this version do what I need.
@Otaku thanks for your answer, it was very nice solution and it is the best version for people who can't(or don't want) use WebDav.
[Here is](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/publish-your-calendar-on-a-webdav-server-HA010356312.aspx) how to publish it.
**EDIT:** In this case calendar opens as readonly because it located on server and cannot be synchronized with existing calendar without add-in, so @Otaku's answer is right.
My version can be used if you don't need synchronization.